# How far from Earth were the Apollo astronauts when they left the Earth's magnetosphere?

Tags: apollo-program, radiation, earth, magnetosphere

I am assuming the Apollo missions recorded radiation levels as they travelled to the Moon.  Have those records ever been released, as a way of determining when the Apollo astronauts left the magnetosphere?

Comment: The question in the title could be answered using current understanding of the shape of the Earth's magnetosphere, but in your question you are asking about Apollo-based measurements. Would an answer to either one be acceptable, or are you most interested in experimental measurements made by the Apollo spacecraft itself?

Comment: @uhoh. I am curious where interplanetary space begins, and how it varies.  Is the Apollo mission data the best source of the information on the shape of the magnetosphere or did orbiting probes provide the better information?  I have yet to find a definitive answer elsewhere, so I thought the measurements of Apollo might be a good source.

Comment: There have been many dedicated missions to measure & map the magnetosphere in great detail over the decades. I think you could ask two separate questions 1) *What measurements of radiation were made by Apollo missions on their way between the Earth and the Moon, both outside and inside the capsule?* and 2) *What is the shape of the Earth's magnetosphere, and which missions contributed to mapping it?* For the second question, you should include a bit of your own research, perhaps a mention of a Wikipedia article and the name of one mission, to avoid people asking "what research have you done?"

Comment: You can also include a link to [your Astronomy question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28957/7982) as background to help explain why you are asking. The more you include describing what you are looking for, the easier it is to answer.